# How get identifier for vendor from website?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, udid

How can I get the identifier for vendor of my iPhone from a website page ? 
For example I create a Cydia repo, and I want that only peoples who paid for my tweak can download it. 
So to do that I need a system who can get the ID from website and save it when client buy the tweak, and compare it with stored one when the client try to download the tweak from Cydia.

Thank.

Comment: Please show us a code example where you have problems with. This is too general.

Comment: I haven’t some code... it’s just theoritical but don’t know how to start...